Make a first level menu vertical when there is an overflow caused from a change in the font-size in the browser setting for accessibility reasons
I'm creating a simple first level menu (here I have a minimum reproducible example) with flexbox. When there isn't enough horizontal space for the seven links I make the menu vertical with a simple media query (the breackpoint is 650 pixels and I'm using the desktop first approach).
However for accessibility reasons I must ensure that with a zoom of the text the content is still OK (no overflow) but it's not the case.  If I make a zoom with CTRL + is ok but if I increase the font-size in the browser setting the seven links exceeds the container and in this case I don't know the right breakpoint.
I could use flex-wrap:wrap on the ul tag but in this way the links breaks to a new line one at a time instead I would the menu becomes vertical right away.  You can simulate an increased font-size in the browser with font-size:2em on the html tag (there is a comment in the code). Here it is the code:
     * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      /* html {
        font-size: 2em;
      } */

      body {
        margin: 0;
      }

      .main-menu {
        border: 3px solid rgb(230, 121, 38);
        padding-block: 0.5rem;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      .main-menu ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
      }

      .main-menu ul li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 0.7rem;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-align: center;
      }

      @media (max-width: 650px) {
        .main-menu ul {
          flex-direction: column;
        }
      }

<nav class="main-menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

I could anticipate the breakpoint (a bigger breackpoint) to make the menu vertical for a font-size:2em but I don't like thi solution. Is there a solution in css only to handle this situation? If not, does it exist a javascript solution?

Using JS you could compare the width of the text container with the width of parent element and use a conditional to check if text container is wider than the parent container, if so change your menu to vertical.

@dalelandry Good idea.   but is there really no solution in css only? WIth gridbox,flexbox or classic css (float,display:inline-block).....   Furthermore with your idea if the user set a bigger font dimension in the browser after he opens the page the overflow will stay still there.
Unfortunately the overflow event isn't standard

I found a simple solution on my own in css only. It's enough to set the breackpoint in em and in this manner the modified (also in the browser setting) font-size change automatically the breackpoint. It's very simple. So, I changed 650px to 40.625em
This is the code:
 function checkMenuOverflow() {
        const menuContainer = document.querySelector(".main-menu");
        const menu = document.querySelector(".main-menu ul");
        const menuWidth = menu.clientWidth; // Larghezza effettiva del contenuto
        console.log(" ~ checkMenuOverflow ~ menuWidth:", menuWidth);
        const containerWidth = menuContainer.clientWidth; // Larghezza del contenitore visibile
        console.log(" ~ checkMenuOverflow ~ containerWidth:", containerWidth);

        if (menuWidth > containerWidth) {
          menu.classList.add("vertical"); // Se c'è overflow, aggiungi la classe per layout verticale
        } else {
          if (menu.clientHeight < containerWidth) {
            console.log(" ~ checkMenuOverflow ~ menu.clientHeight:", menu.clientHeight);
            menu.classList.remove("vertical"); // Altrimenti, rimuovi la classe verticale
          }
        }
      }

      // Verifica overflow quando la pagina viene caricata

      checkMenuOverflow();

      // Verifica overflow quando la finestra viene ridimensionata
      window.addEventListener("resize", checkMenuOverflow);

      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      /* html {
        font-size: 2em;
      } */

      body {
        margin: 0;
      }

      .main-menu {
        border: 3px solid rgb(230, 121, 38);
        padding-block: 0.5rem;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      .main-menu ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-shrink: 0;
      }

      .main-menu ul.vertical {
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      .main-menu ul li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 0.7rem;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-align: center;
      }

      @media (max-width: 40.625em) {
        .main-menu ul {
          flex-direction: column;
        }
      }

 <nav class="main-menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>


You could achieve something like this using CSS @container queries.


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.resize {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main-menu {
  /* border: 3px solid rgb(230, 121, 38);*/
  padding-block: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* define main menu as container reference */
  container-type: inline-size;
}

.main-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}


/* switch to vertical layout if menu is less than 32rem wide */

@container (max-width: 32rem) {
  .main-menu ul {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.main-menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.7rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
<div class="resize">
  <nav class="main-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>



We need to define the parent menu/nav as a container reference by applying
  container-type: inline-size;

Then we can define a container query - very similar to a media query:
/* switch to vertical layout if menu is less than 32rem wide */
@container (max-width: 32rem) {
  .main-menu ul {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

Further reading
"Container Queries: a Quick Start Guide"

Your solution is ok, but is more simple and direct the solution in my answer where it's enough to use em in the breackpoint without container queries.
